# Function searching for applicable types for applying to Lensed pieces of Haskell AST

Tags: haskell

My primary queston is: **is there, within some Haskell AST, a way I can determine a list of the available declarations, and their types**? I'm trying to build an editor that allows for the user to be shown all the appropriate edits available, such as inserting functions and/or other declared values that can be used or inserted at any point. It'll also disallows syntax errors as well as type-errors. (That is, it'll be a semantic structural editor, which I'll also use the typechecker to make sure the editing pieces make sense to in this case, Haskell).

The second part of my question is: once I have that list, given a particular expression or function or focussed-on piece of AST (using `Lens`), how could I filter the list based on what could possibly replace or fit that particular focussed-on AST piece (whether by providing arguments to a function, or if it's a value, just "as-is"). Perhaps I need to add some concrete example here... something like: "Haskell, which declarations could possibly be applied (for functions) and/or placed into the hole at `yay x y z = (x + y - z) * _`?" then if there was an expression `number2 :: Num a => a ; number2 = 23` it would put this in the list, as well as the functions available in the context, as well as those from `Num` itself such as `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, and any other declarations that resulted in a type that would match such as `Num a => a` etc. etc.

More details follow:

I’ve done a fair bit of research into this area over quite a long time: looked at and used `hint`, `Language.Haskell.Exts` and `Control.Lens` a fair bit. Also had a look into `Dynamic`. `Control.Lens` is relevant for the second half of my question. I've also looked at quite a few projects along the way including Conal Elliott's "Semantic Editing Combinators", Paul Chiusano's Unison system and quite a few things in Clojure and Lisp as well.

So, I know I can get a list of the exports of a module with hint as `[String]`, and I could coerce that to `[Dynamic]`, I think (possibly?), but I’m not sure how I’d get *sub-function* declarations and their types. (Maybe I could take the declarations within that scope with AST and put them in their own modules in a String and pull them in by getting the top level declarations with hint? that would work but feels hacky and cumbersome)

I can use `(:~:)` from `Data.Typeable` to do "propositional equality" (ie typechecking?) on two terms, but what I actually need to do is see if a term could be matched into a position in the source/AST (I'm using lenses and prisms to focus on those parts of the AST) given some number of arguments. Some kind of partial type-checking, or result type-checking? Because the thing I might be focussing on could very well be a function, and I might need to keep the same arity.

I feel like perhaps this is very similar to Idris' term-searching, though I haven't looked into the source for that and I'm not sure if that's something only possible in a dependently typed language.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Any potential answer would depend entirely on how you have chosen to represent Haskell terms and types; unless you are building your own Haskell typechecker as well (which you would have to do to somehow make this based on `Dynamic`), the same representation used by the GHC api would probably be an obvious choice. The GHC api would also allow you to lookup declarations based on type. After that, the answer to your 2nd question depends entirely on how hard you want your editor to try to find a potential answer (do you try to unify the target type with every declaration in scope? probably not)

Comment: I'm using `Language.Haskell.Exts`, sorry if I didn't make that clear enough. This *is* the GHCI API representation. (Assuming I'm understanding what you mean by the GHC API). I'm not basing it on `Dynamic`, I just thought maybe `Dynamic` would let me grab a whole bunch of expressions and/or functions in a list (because that's the easiest way to have a heterogenous list). Yeah, I'd like to unify the target type with every declaration in scope if possible, "closest" scopes first. *update*: sorry, now I see you mean the GHC package. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: To be clear, I mean [the GHC API](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.2/index.html). The reason I said 'probably not' is because unifying two random types which happen to be in scope is not likely to succeed, but can be very expensive; this could really harm the usability of your program. No program (IDE, typechecker) I know of does a perfect job of this, for any language with a rich type system, so if you should look to examples of such to figure out precisely what kind of functionality you want to attain (it is an entirely non-trivial problem!)

Comment: This is a very long and quite abstract question. Would it be possible to narrow it down to a concrete example? This usually helps a lot to get attention and specific solutions. See also [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @PetrPudlák I agree it's annoying. However, not all questions are short, and this problem is also actually quite abstract in nature. Believe it or not, *this* actually *is* more concrete than the actual problem I'm trying to solve. I might close it. user2407038 has pointed me in a good direction, which is what I was after more than anything. Part of the problem there is I don't want to lead anyone to a particular solution, and my problem is not specifically concrete. WDYT? What should I do?

Comment: @JulianLeviston I understand. Approaching a very general problem with an unclear solution might be an overwhelming task with unexpected blockers. I'd suggest to try to solve a more specific case and then iterating to the more general one. For example, as user2407038 suggests, an important thing is how you represent your terms and types. I'd try to pick one and try to work with it. If there will be a problem, you'll know what else representation to choose and why. Similarly, you can start with a simpler language, perhaps the Hindley-Milner type system, and then extend it later to Haskell.

Comment: Yep. Classic divide and conquer (I'm by no means a software development beginner, by the way). I *am* trying to solve a specific case. I built a small toy grammar and a few functions, but it's the same problem. It's irrelevant how I represent types. The things that were "blocking" me were primarily "how to get a list of top level declarations" which I've found out how to do using `hint`, and secondarily "how to filter those declarations based on their result value type". Not sure how to do the second one, but I'll find out, or ask again more simply in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I kind of answered my own questions, so I'm going to do so formally here.

The answer to the first part of my question can be found in the `Reflection` module of the `hint` library. I knew I could get a list a `[String]` of these modules, but there's a function in there that can be used which has type: `getModuleExports :: MonadInterpreter m => ModuleName -> m [ModuleElem]` and is most likely the sort of thing I'm after. This is because `hint` provides access to a large part of the GHC API. It also provides some lookup functions which I can then use to get the types of these top level terms.

https://github.com/mvdan/hint/blob/master/src/Hint/Reflection.hs#L30

Also, Template Haskell provides *some* of the functionality I'm interested in, and I'll probably end up using quite a bit of that to build my functions, or at least a set of lenses for whatever syntax is being used by the code (/text) under consideration.

In terms of the second part of the question, I still don't have a particularly good answer, so my first attempt will be to use some `String` munging on the output of the lookup functions and see what I can do.